# Google Javascript Maps Api Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (OK)

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

Currently I'm working on a Ionic Framework project using Angularjs, where I'm using google maps JavaScript api to load maps, and for google autocomplete service. Whenever I generate an api key from google developer console, it works for three to four days and later it will returns the following error:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?5m2&1d13.0191…IzaSyDjoCgi81YIxt0V3G6NLwrjbcGlx50c0hQ&callback=_xdc_._i4q60t&token=115527 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (OK)`

And for google auto-complete service it shows the following error:

`GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AutocompletionService.GetPrediction…AIzaSyDjoCgi81YIxt0V3G6NLwrjbcGlx50c0hQ&callback=_xdc_._n5gk1d&token=50750`

I'm very sure that i'm not exceeding the free quota.

Comment: Both results should return an error-code in the status-property, what's the code?

Comment: It returns 403 (OK). @Dr.Molle

Comment: I do not mean the HTTP-status, e.g. a geocoder-result contains a status: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes  ...

Comment: This is the server reply:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (OK)    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2F%23%2Ftab%2Fjourney&4sAIzaSyDjoCgi81YIxt0V3G6NLwrjbcGlx50c0hQ&callback=_xdc_._ms6tgd&token=28387   and for Geocode service: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (OK)  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?5m2&1d13.0191257&2d77.64935409999998&7sUS&9sen-US&key=AIzaSyDjoCgi81YIxt0V3G6NLwrjbcGlx50c0hQ&callback=_xdc_._41b8li&token=95790

Comment: If I'll regenerate the API key in google developer console to load this: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"
  type="text/javascript"></script> then it will work for three or four days and then again it will throw above mentioned error.

Comment: In google developer console do we have to give our credit cards credential to use free quota?  @Dr.Molle

Comment: no, you only need to give them when you enable billing

Comment: OK. But please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: can you give a link to a page that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Can I share you my screen on Skype? Because to run this files I'm using ionic framework and many javascript files.

Comment: Thank You for replying Dr. Molle. I have solved the problem. From this <script src="maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"; type="text/javascript"></script> link i was downloading javascript content and i was storing it locally. So I'm calling it directly in HTML page. Once again thank you for replying to my query.

Comment: Can you post your solution in more detail as an answer? I am having the same issue.